# different ways to define a function as template argument explitcly passed or not

Tags: c++, templates

Let:

```
int id(int x) { return x; }
```

The following code compiles with GCC:

```
template <typename F> int f2(F f, int x) { return f(x); }

int id2(int x) { return f2(id, x); }
```

But the following does not compile:

```
template <typename F> int f1(int x) { return F(x); }

int id1(int x) { return f1<id>(x); }
```

Can somebody please explain what is wrong with this?

Comment: `f(x)` will invoke function, while `F(x)` will construct a new object of type `F`.

Comment: Yes, but `F f; f(x)` does not work either.  Nor does `F f; (*f)(x)`.

Comment: `F f;` will declare a new (potentially uninitialized) object of type `F`. Even if you correctly pass a function type as template parameter by writing `f1<decltype(&id)>` it still won't work. You can try passing it as a non-type template parameter by changing template declaration to `template<int ( * f )(int x)>`. Alternatively, if your compiler supports C++17 you can simplify it by utilizing automatic non-type template parameter deduction `template<auto f>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not compile because `typename F` expects a type, while you're giving it a function, e.g. `int(*F)(int)` which is a non-type template parameter.

```
int id(int x) { return x; }

template <int(*F)(int)> // here
int f1(int x) { return F(x); }

int id1(int x) { return f1<id>(x); }
```

This could be further simplified and made more generic with C++17:

```
template <auto F> 
int f1(int x) { return F(x); }
```